# Unable to use Gmail in Thunderbird 3

Tags: gmail, thunderbird, gmail-imap

Mozilla Thunderbird **v.3.1.7**
I am trying to setup Gmail, but none of the settings are working. I have tried every resource:

1. Blogs, tutorials
2. Instructions by Google
3. Instructions by Thunderbird
4. Questions here

But, still its not working.
My settings are as follows

***Server Settings***

```
Server Type: IMAP Mail server
Server Name: imap.gmail.com
Username: user@gmail.com
Port: 993
Default: 993
Connection Security: SSL/TLS
Authentication method: Encrypted password
```

***Outgoing server (SMTP)***

```
Server Name: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 587
Default: 25
Connection Security: STARTTLS
Authentication method: Encrypted password
Username: user@gmail.com
```

IMAP is enabled in my Gmail settings.

**ERROR:** Connection to the server user@gmail.com timed out.

I am behind a proxy server and I have configured those settings under:
Thunderbird Preferences -> Advanced -> Network and Disk Space -> Connection Settings -> Manual Proxy Configuration

The proxy configuration works, as when I created a Blogs and News feeds a/c, it was working properly and fetching the feeds for me. So, Thunderbird is configured properly as per the proxy settings.

Help me.

Comment: What kind of proxy is it? Maybe it only allows HTTP and not other protocols? News feeds use the same HTTP as web browsing, and mail protocols are entirely different.

Comment: @grawity: I don't have much knowledge of what kind of proxy is it. May be you could ask me to do some stuff, and i will post the output that would let you know the kind of proxy

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the:

- **Authentication Method** on Server settings to Normal Password
- **Port** on Outgoing server to 465
- **Connection security** on Outgoing server to SSL/TLS
- **Authentication Method** on Outgoing server to Normal Password

Comment: +1 for changing to "Normal password". The outgoing mail port is correct though (implicit SSL on 465 is deprecated).

Comment: That didn't work for me :(. Is there any other way, or you have any idea why it didn't work.

Comment: @Jatin: I've just tested these with different accounts, and they all work fine (I'm using a proxy as well). Are you setting up your account manually? If so, try using the Main Account Setup and try not to change anything else. Also, you're using an older version of Thunderbird, so download the latest off of Mozilla's web site and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

brevity is the soul of wit or some such :-)
https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/Thunderbird+and+Gmail
https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/Configure+an+Account
http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180189

if the above don't help then you have an WiFi, Ethernet or router issue (or anti-virus), not a Thunderbird issue

Comment: Well, I have gone through all of them, in case you didn't read the question well. I have tried every resource on the web, and it doesn't work. **AND** I am a college student using Ubuntu 10.04, so No Viruses, and I am on Ethernet behind a proxy server.

Comment: then perhaps it's time to check your proxy server again. many folks including myself use ubuntu and thunderbird and gmail
and to PhillyG: googlemail and gmail SMTP servers both work; it's confusing but google has verified that both should work

Comment: `I am a college student using Ubuntu 10.04, so No Viruses` I chuckled a little.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.... I have gmail working in Thunderbird. I use

Outgoing Server (SMTP): Google Mail - smtp.googlemail.com

rather than the smtp.gmail.com you mention.

The settings for Google Mail are

- Server Name: smtp.googlemail.com
- Port: 465    Default: 465
- Connection security:    SSL/TLS
- Authentication method:      Normal password
- User Name:   xxxxxxxx@gmail.com

Try those!

Answer (score 0):

It was not working for me either. The only thing that I had to do was to put the IP address `209.85.143.16` because `imap.google.com` could not be resolved. Same situation with SMTP. Try to ping this address from behind proxy server. If you get response than it's something else.